# Change URL on scroll not working in chrome and opera

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following script to change the url hash when scrolling to a section of a one page website. This is working perfect in ie and firefox, but not in chrome and opera and i cant figure it out.

```
(jQuery)(function ($) {

    // CHANGE URL ON SCROLL
    $(function () {
        var currentHash = "#intro"
        $(document).scroll(function () {
            $('section').each(function () {
                var top = window.pageYOffset;
                var distance = top - $(this).offset().top;
                var hash = $(this).attr('id');

                if (distance < 30 && distance > -30 && currentHash != hash) {
                    window.location.hash = (hash);
                    currentHash = hash;
                }
            });
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Did you close the IIEF?

Comment: Yes the code is correct in this way.

Comment: Ok, we might need some HTML. Does de the Console output from Chrome and/or Opera shows some error/warning messages?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$("body").offset().top` instead of `window.pageYOffset`

Comment: Then the url is not changing anymore.